# Cannot assign \c{char} to a const variable

Tags: languages, expl3, characters

Why and is there a solution?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\inputencoding{latin1}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_const:Nx \lang_and
{
  croatian=i,
  czech=a,
  hungarian=\'es,
%  romanian=\c{s}i, % ERROR: Illegal parameter number in definition of \erw_foo.
  slovak=a,
  slovenian=in
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ifcsdef{c}{
  romanian=\c{s}i,
  }{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Apparently `\c{s}` does not survive the `\edef` of `\tl_const:Nx`, with `\tl_const:Nn` there is no error.

Comment: Because `\c` is not expandable (neither is `\'`: try `\show \lang_and` to see), and it explodes with `x` expansion. Either use `\tl_const:Nn` or use `\exp_not:n { romanian=\c{s}i }` to avoid the expansion of `\c`. Besides the name of `\lang_and` is wrong: something like `\c_erwann_lang_tl` would be better.

Comment: Are you defining a token list constant or rather a clist? And what's the reason for `x`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Because \c is not expandable (neither is \': try \show \lang_and to
>   see), and it explodes with x expansion. Either use \tl_const:Nn or use
>   \exp_not:n { romanian=\c{s}i } to avoid the expansion of \c  – Phelype Oleinik

Answer (score 3):

I can see no reason for

1. `\inputencoding{latin1}` after loading `utf8`;
2. a token list constant;
3. `x` expansion.

Most likely you want

```latex
\prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn \g_erwann_lang_and_prop
 {
  croatian=i,
  czech=a,
  hungarian=\'es,
  romanian=\textcommabelow{s}i,
  slovak=a,
  slovenian=in
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I didn't put to much thought into 1. The reasons for 2. and 3. wouldn't add value to the discussion.